# Dynamically adding more attributes to a TypeScript Class/Object

Tags: attributes, typescript

I have a class in TypeScript that goes as follows:

```
export class Node {
    id: number;
}
```

Now during runtime, my script loads a .json file which contains many nodes. Each of those nodes has different attributes. I create a new Object of class Node for each node I load and add the attributes the specific loaded node to the node object.

How can I achieve this using the Node class above? Right now I am using **any** to make it work:

```
export class Main {
    private nodes: any[] = []; // I'd like to use the class Node instead of any here

    constructor() {
        // load json
        var loadedNodes = jsonload("data.json");

        // okay, json loaded
        // now load the json into objects
        for (var nodeIndex in loadedNodes) {
            // check whether the attribute that you are finding is from the object itself and not from up the prototype chain
            if (loadedNodes.hasOwnProperty(nodeIndex)) {
                var loadedNode = loadedNodes.nodes[nodeIndex];
                var node: any = {}; // I'd like to use the class Node instead of any here
                for (var key in loadedNode) {
                    if (loadedNode.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        node[key] = loadedNode[key]; // put the attribute into the node object
                    }
                }
                this.nodes.push(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Example data for "data.json":

```
{"nodes":[{"test": "bla","name":"Myriel","group":1}, {"name":"Napoleon","group":2},{"name":"StackOverflow","group":1}]}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at `var node: any = {};` A literal object is being created instead of an instance of `Node`.

---

You can either use the `Node` class by doing:

```
var node = new Node();
```

---

Or you can make the `Node` class an interface instead:

```
interface INode {
    // Needs to be optional if the object is going to be empty at first.
    id?: string;
}

// Then define the `node` variable with the interface:

var node: INode = {};
```